# Evaluador Posfijo

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Quiero crear un Evaluador Postfix que funcione con múltiples dígitos y números decimales. El programa funciona con múltiples dígitos pero no con decimales. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? He usado la expresión infija: `"10 + 20 * (50/3) + 4"`, que en postfix es `"10 20 50 3 / * + 4 +"`. Como resultado, obtuve `347.33333333333337`, que es correcto. Solo necesito que el evaluador trabaje con números decimales, pero no sé cómo lograr esto. Espero su respuesta, muchas gracias.

```
public class EvaluarExpresion {

    public static double evaluaExpresion (String postfija) {
        MyStack<Double> stack = new MyStack<Double>();
        //String postfija= expresionPostFijo();
        for(int i = 0; i < postfija.length(); i++) { 
            char c = postfija.charAt(i); 
            if(c == ' ') {
                continue; 
            }else if(Character.isDigit(c)) { 
                int n = 0; 
                while(Character.isDigit(c)) { 
                    n = n*10 + (int)(c-'0'); 
                    i++; 
                    c = postfija.charAt(i); 
                } 
                i--; 
                stack.push((double) n); 
            } else {
                Double val1 = stack.pop(); 
                Double val2 = stack.pop(); 
                switch(c) 
                { 
                    case '+': 
                    stack.push(val2+val1); 
                    break; 

                    case '-': 
                    stack.push(val2- val1); 
                    break; 

                    case '/': 
                    stack.push(val2/val1); 
                    break; 

                    case '*': 
                    stack.push(val2*val1); 
                    break; 

                    case '^': 
                    stack.push(Math.pow(val2, val1)); 
                    break; 
                } 
            }      
        }
        return stack.pop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is an example of an infix expression  String dato = "10 + 20 * ( 50 / 3 ) + 4"; 
        //The expression provided below is a postfix expression
        System.out.println(a.evaluaExpresion("10 20 50 3 / * + 4 +")); 
        //The result is 347.33333333333337 which is correct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto:

```
while(Character.isDigit(c)) { 
    n = n*10 + (int)(c-'0'); 
    i++; 
    c = postfija.charAt(i); 
}
```

A esto:

```
double decimales = 0.0;
while(Character.isDigit(c) || (c == '.' && decimales == 0.0)) {
    if (decimales > 0) decimales++;
    if (c == '.') {
      decimales = 1.0;
    } else {
      n = n*10 + (int)(c-'0'); 
    }
    i++; 
    c = postfija.charAt(i); 
}
n = n / Math.pow(10,decimales);
```